# JSLint Weird assignment, required for closure compiler

Tags: jslint, google-closure-compiler, jshint

I'm using the closure compiler to minify and speed up my code but I'm running into some issues with JSLint when I try to [export my functions](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#export).

Basically, I have an object, `foo{}` with a function, `foo.bar()` that gets called via an external file as. In order for this function to be called externally I need to add some declarations to my script before it gets compiled:

```
window['foo'] = foo;
window['foo']['bar'] = foo.bar;
```

This works great, but—as ever—JSLint thinks I'm mental for even attempting this. I've managed to suppress the dot notation error by declaring, `/*jslint sub: true */` just before these two lines but I still get the following error:

```
"window['foo']['bar'] = foo.bar;" - Weird assignment
```

It's not wrong, it is a weird assignment out of context, but I need it in there in order for my code to work.

The way I see it, I have three possible options:

1. Tell JSLint not to bother even looking at them two lines.
2. Suppress the `Weird assignment` error.
3. Find another way to make my code work with closure compiler.

The problem is, I have no idea how to go about doing any of them.

Comment: I might be missing something from what seems to be an incomplete sentence "gets called via an external file as," but that aside -- If `window['foo']` is set to `foo`, and `foo.bar` already exists, why do you need to push it into `window.foo.bar`? It's already there. Might need a little more code to know exactly what you're doing, though admittedly I'm not familiar with Closure Compiler. From what I quickly skimmed from your link, saying `window.foo = foo;` would accomplish essentially the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. When closure compiler runs it turns `foo.bar()` into `a.b()` (or something similar) so I can't call it in the usual way. Setting `window['foo']` allows me to do this, as outlined in the [closure docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?csw=1#export).

Does that clear it up at all? It's a little difficult to explain.

Comment: I've caught up. You need *all* the names to translate after the compilation translation, so you're explicitly putting `foo` *and* `bar` on `window` so you don't end up with `window.foo.b()` after the compiler runs. Ouch. I'd still be interested in hearing if the compiler does the same thing with dot notation (so [like this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VWHz8ngn)) rather than subscript notation, but if not, that is, if the compiler *only recognizes subscript notation*, you might be stuck. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export names using `goog.exportSymbol` instead of bracket notation: https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js#L1532

The Closure Compiler understands what `goog.exportSymbol` is so it'll remove the explicit exportSymbol call and add `foo` and `bar` directly to the window for you.

Comment: This could be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm away from my machine at the moment but I'll try it out when I get home, thanks!